# Set navigation item from UINavigationController extension

Tags: swift

I wrote a function to show my app logo in the middle of the navigation bar, and it is working fine when I call it from viewDidLoad() function.

But, when I tried to add it to a UINavigationController extension, it is not working! Although the function is called, the logo does not appear.

Any idea?

Thanks

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func showNavLogo(){
        let imageW = 59
        let imageH = 30
        
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Logo.png")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
        let currWidth = self.navigationItem.titleView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(imageW))
        currWidth?.isActive = true
        let currHeight = self.navigationItem.titleView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(imageH))
        currHeight?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding the function to UIViewController extension instead of UINavigationController

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showNavLogo(){
        let imageW = 59
        let imageH = 30
        
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Logo.png")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
        
        let currWidth = self.navigationItem.titleView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(imageW))
        currWidth?.isActive = true
        let currHeight = self.navigationItem.titleView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(imageH))
        currHeight?.isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: ok. great, glad you have it solved. i think it didn't work before because your view controller wasn't connected to Navigation controller on the storyboard

Comment: good solution, it was worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to call self.showNavLogo() in your viewDidload?

your extension means you have a function called showNavlogo, but you may still have to call the showlogo method by using the self..showNavLogo() in your viewDidload or viewWillAppear.

Also ensure your storyboard or View controller or nib is mapped to a Navigation controller for your viewcontroller to implement your method.

Comment: Sure, as I mentioned "Although the function is called, the logo does not appear."

Comment: can you share how you called the extension method in your view controller?.

Answer (score 0):

changing the extension to UIViewcontroller worked for me